# connecting aws rds(postgres db) and sqs

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-sqs

i have a postgresql database in amazon rds,i want to send a message to aws sqs when there is a new record inserted  in to the database tables, how can i do that??

Comment: Are you using Postgres or Dynamo?

Comment: i am using postgres db

Answer (score 2):

Currently, there's no way to send data directly from PostgresSQL on AWS RDS to an AWS SQS queue.

However, as of April of 2021, AWS has made possible for PostgreSQL instances on RDS to [call AWS Lambda functions directly](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/04/amazon-rds-postgresql-integrates-aws-lambda/).

The full documentation of the integration can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/PostgreSQL-Lambda.html).

Using this integration, you can create an AFTER INSERT trigger on the desired table, that sends the info about the NEW row to a Lambda function, and have this function create an event for an SQS queue. An example of how to do this using Node.js can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/sqs-examples-send-receive-messages.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DynamoDb Streams` and [connect](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.Lambda.html) it to a `Lambda`, which will be triggered by changes in your `DynamoDB` and gets the changed record. Then you can insert the record into `SQS`.

Comment: Why is the title of your question 'connecting aws dynamodb and sqs' then?

Comment: yup,sorry i have updated the question now,sorry for that,but i am using postgres db